# Windows command line: setting global variables to each other

Tags: command-line

**scenario further updated**

Hi all:

I'm trying to set a global variable to another in windows command line batch language.  The syntax I've tried is as below:

```
:: these are global vars
SET varThree=%varOne%\something
SET varOne=
SET varTwo=2

:Section
SET varOne=%varTwo%
::more setting of varOne to other global variables
GOTO Section2

:Section2
echo %varThree%
GOTO cleanup

:cleanup
SET varThree=
SET varTwo=
SET varOne=
```

The value of varOne seems to be lost when it comes to echoing %varThree%.

I was wondering how can I set the above variable properly?

TIA.

***EDIT:***
The cleanup section was there as a way to ensure the variables are being cleaned up upon exiting of the program.  When I removed it, it took the 2nd run in order for varOne to lose its state.  Likewise when I re-introduced it, it took the 2nd run for the state of varOne to come back.  Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the percent signs on the left side.
Also, you might want to read about delay-expanded variables (like !varTwo! instead of %varTwo%), since you might run into problems with incorrect expansions.
See this link about delayed expansions: [Cmd.exe Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true)

Edit: You're also missing a "Set" on the left, so this:

```
:Section
%varOne%=%varTwo%
```

Should really be:

```
:Section
Set varOne=%varTwo%
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. My bad, my scenario was vague and not to the point. I've updated my scenario.  The value of the global variable somehow got lost and didnt get set properly.

Comment: I also happen to get the same result from the code in your comment.  I have further updated the scenario and have found the cause of the problem, but struggling to find a solution to solve it.

Comment: nevermind my situation.  I have the problem solved.  I think I was declaring one of the global variables twice somewhere else.  In regards to the question in topic, your solution worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
varOne=%varTwo%
```

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong in looking for a "post-compiling" syntax.
In your scenario

```
SET varThree=%varOne%\something
```

cause varThree set with "\something", because varOne is not defined yet.
Speaking about your scenario, you have to use

```
echo %varOne%%varThree%
```

in ":section2".